# What does it mean for an NSObjectController to be in Entity Mode?

Tags: objective-c

Hey I was going through the apple docs, when I came across this line: 
"NSObjectController and its subclasses, when in entity mode, can now fetch lazily". There were no further clarifications, does anyone happen to know what it means for an NSObjectController to be in Entity mode?

Answer (score 0):

Entity mode is for use with Core Data.